# Under mathspec, use text font punctuation symbols in math mode

Tags: xetex, mathspec

I am managing a XeLaTeX template for editing my own books, which, under `mathspec`, allows me to pick some font families in my catalog and use them in the document.

Unfortunately, since frequently the discussion treats math equations as part of the text instead of formulas being shown, I want to take the main punctuation symbols of the *text* font (`,`, `.`, `;` and `:`) and use them in the *math* mode.

The fonts used for *text* and for *math* are different and, the farthest I've done is to take one of the *math* fonts subsets (`Digits`, `Latin` or `Greek`) to use the punctuation, but none of these font sets used for *math* mode has the same punctuation symbols used in *text* mode.

Sorry for including all the packages I normally use, but trying to remove some of them I think are unnecessary to provide a MWE gave me some random errors.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setdefaultlanguage{brazil}
\geometry{a5paper, left=2.000cm, right=2.000cm, top=2.800cm, bottom=2.800cm}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Ligatures=TeX}

% ?

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1

% Declaring Font Families

\newfontfamily{\setpunctfont}[
    Path            = ./fonts/text/ ,
    UprightFont     = regular.otf ,
    BoldFont        = regular.otf ,
    ItalicFont      = regular.otf ,
    BoldItalicFont  = regular.otf ,
    Scale           = MatchLowercase ,
    NFSSFamily      = puncty
    ]{jPunct}

\setmainfont[
    Path            = ./fonts/text/ ,
    UprightFont     = regular.otf ,
    BoldFont        = bold.otf ,
    ItalicFont      = italic.otf ,
    BoldItalicFont  = bold-italic.otf ,
    Scale           = MatchLowercase
    ]{jMain}

\setmathfont(Latin)[
    Path            = ./fonts/math/ ,
    UprightFont     = latin.otf ,
    BoldFont        = latin.otf ,
    ItalicFont      = latin.otf ,
    BoldItalicFont  = latin.otf ,
    Scale           = MatchLowercase
    ]{jMathLatin}

% ?

\makeatletter
    \ifx\e@alloc@intercharclass@top\@undefined
        \chardef\CharBound=255
    \else
        \chardef\CharBound=\e@alloc@intercharclass@top
    \fi
\makeatother

\chardef\CharBase=0
\newXeTeXintercharclass\CharPcts
\XeTeXcharclass"002C=\CharPcts
\XeTeXcharclass"002E=\CharPcts
\XeTeXcharclass"003A=\CharPcts
\XeTeXcharclass"003B=\CharPcts
\newtoks\TokenPunctFont
\TokenPunctFont={\begingroup\setpunctfont}
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharBase\CharPcts=\TokenPunctFont
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharBound\CharPcts=\TokenPunctFont
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharPcts\CharBase={\normalfont\endgroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharPcts\CharBound={\normalfont\endgroup}

\DeclareSymbolFont{PunctSymb}{TU}{puncty}{m}{n}
\Umathchardef\MathPunctComma="3 \symPunctSymb "002C
\Umathchardef\MathPunctDot="3 \symPunctSymb "002E
\Umathchardef\MathPunctSemiColon="3 \symPunctSymb "003B
\Umathchardef\MathPunctColon="3 \symPunctSymb "003A

\begin{document}

    ASP.<> $ASP.;,:<>$ \textbf{A.B,C} \textit{A,B;C.}.  $\MathPunctDot$.

\end{document}
```

So, I want *math* `.` to correspond to `\MathPunctDot` and I can fix properly the another three punctuation symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through XeLaTeX documentation, you can use, instead of `\Umathchardef`, the command `\Umathcode`. Since you want to change the punctuation symbols to keep them like *text* mode, then you can set up the following:

1. You do not need a separate font family for punctuation. Declare `NFSSFamily` for your main font instead.

   ```
   \setmainfont[
       Path            = ./fonts/text/ ,
       UprightFont     = regular.otf ,
       BoldFont        = bold.otf ,
       ItalicFont      = italic.otf ,
       BoldItalicFont  = bold-italic.otf ,
       Scale           = MatchLowercase ,
       NFSSFamily      = puncty
   ]{jMain}
   ```
2. The declaration

   ```
   \DeclareSymbolFont{PunctSymb}{TU}{puncty}{m}{n}
   ```

   now handles directly your main font. You can declare the *math mode* punctuation symbols after this declaration as follows:

   ```
   \Umathcode"002C="6 \symPunctSymb "002C
   \Umathcode"002E="6 \symPunctSymb "002E
   \Umathcode"003A="6 \symPunctSymb "003A
   \Umathcode"003B="6 \symPunctSymb "003B
   ```

   The `6` index stands for math punctuation.
3. I recommend you to remove `fdsymbol` package if you want or need to work with more fonts, otherwise you will likely be greeted by the error `Too many fonts declared`.